# simple_form_for with localized, scoped routes and Mongoid (missing required keys: [:id])

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, simple-form, rails-i18n

I have a `_form.html.haml` partial for a model `FileType` that I want to render in my `new.html.haml` and `edit.html.haml` view.

```
= simple_form_for [:document_manager, file_type] do |f|
    ...
```

When I render this partial in the **new** view, this works, but when I render it in the **edit** view, `simple_form` tries to set the `id` of `file_type` to the `locale` param if my route. My routes look like this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  scope '(:locale)', locale: locale: /#{I18n.available_locales.join('|')}/ do
    namespace :document_manager do
      resources :file_types, except: [:show]
    end
  end
end
```

For the **new** view the route `/en/document_manager/file_types` is generated, but when I try to access the **edit** view I get this error:

```
No route matches {
  :action=>"update", 
  :controller=>"document_manager/file_types", 
  :format=>nil, 
  :id=>nil, 
  :locale=>#<FileType _id: 550198ca7462720388010000, user_file_id: nil, file_name: "...", description: "...">
} missing required keys: [:id]
```

How can I change the form that the `id` and `locale` parameter is set right for **new** and **edit**?

**Update:** A first solution that works is to remove the `locale` scope and store the language in the session, but for SEO, this will result in duplicate content, so a better solution would be having urls like:

- /en/document_manager/file_types
- /fr/document_manager/file_types
- /de/document_manager/file_types
- ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a normal path, some times rails overcomplicates, in this case it should automatically use the scope you are using but as you try to use it I have only used hardcoded scopes like `/en|es|fr/`.

If I were you I would use something like:

```
= simple_form_for document_file_type_path, method: :post do |f|
```

and use 2 different forms, try hardcoding your available locales like

```
scope "(:locale)", :locale => /en|es|fr/ do
  resources :foos
  resources :bars
  ...
```

**EDIT**

Also looks like it is waiting for 3 parameters try:

```
[:document_manager, "locale", file_type]
```